# Unable to create proper authentication with prompt in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating authentication module with `prompt` in javascript. 

Here is my code:

```
var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password',' ');
var originalPass = "mypassword";
if(pass1 == "mypassword"){
 return;
}
else{
 pass1 = prompt('Wrong Password. Please Enter Valid Password',' ');    
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <p>Hello, You are logged in </p>
</body>
</html>
```

In my code, if I enter the wrong password, the program control goes to else loop and display another prompt password field, when I enter the wrong password again at the second time, it loads the page and displays the HTML content. 
What I want to do is, I don't want to get load the page until the user enters the right password.

Comment: I assume this is just a sort of exercise for you because you should never check for password in JavaScript code which runs in the browser. As for your question, you don't load any page in your code so what exactly do you want to protect with the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the correct password either use a **innerHTML** to write the content to your dom, or here I have used `document.write`.

To ask the password continuously from user, add a **while** loop and break it only if the condition is `true`.

```js
var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password');
var originalPass = "mypassword";
while (1) {
  if (pass1 == "mypassword") {
    document.write("<html><head></head><body><p>Hello, You are logged in</p></body></html>");
    break;
  } else {
    pass1 = prompt('Wrong Password. Please Enter Valid Password');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, don't answer with just code. You should add a brief explaination.

Comment: @bhansa Thanks for the answer but how can I show prompt box again and again?

Comment: @Onkar added a while loop for repeated prompt.